# Netbeans Hibernate sample DVDStoreAdmin

Tags: hibernate, netbeans

everybody! I downloaded Netbeans Hibernate sample [DVDStoreAdmin](https://netbeans.org/projects/samples/downloads/download/Samples/Java/DVDStoreAdmin-Ant.zip) from ["Using Hibernate in a Java Swing Application" tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/hibernate-java-se.html#09a). I opened project in NetBeans 8.1 (last version) and got project problems:
1. "hibernate-support" libraty could not be found.
2. "ejb3-persistence" library  could not be found.
3. "mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar" file/folder could not be found.
Where can I find these libraries?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've just solved problems with libs. I simply removed refs to this libs and add refs to Hibernate (which is included in Java Beans). I compiled it successfully, but I got an error

Comment: Initial SessionFactory creation failed.java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/EntityListeners
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: All code is standard from sample. Can anybody help me?